# Selecionar item de uma coluna no Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu consegui filtrar os items que eu quero, porém eles ficam numa espécie de coluna.

Fiz dessa forma:

```
import os

cmd = os.popen('arping -I enp1s0 -c 2 192.168.0.1')  
arr = cmd.read().split('\n')  
for line in arr:  
        if 'Unicast' in line:  
                a = line.split()  
                b = a[4]  
                c = b[1:18]  
                print c
```

O resultado do `print c`, é o endereço MAC do IP, nesse caso ele sai dessa forma.

Exemplo:

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:00  
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:00  
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01
```

Como eu posso pegar, por exemplo, todo o conteúdo que está na linha de baixo, tipo linha 1, 2 ou 3. Tipo eu quero pegar `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01` e colocar ele numa variável.

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você quer fazer. O que seria exatamente "pegar o conteúdo da linha de baixo"? Baixo do que? Quais linhas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Não use o `os.popen`. Para executar subprocessos no python use sempre o módulo `subprocess`, como recomendado na própria [documentação do `popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen).
2. Passe os parâmetros de execução sempre como lista, assim você evita problemas com aspas e caracteres especiais da shell.
3. A sua dúvida está meio confusa. Parece que você quer armazenar todos os mac address associados a um ip, então, fiz uma função que faz exatamente isso. Como pode ser que venham mac address repetidos no resultado do comando, usei um `set` (conjunto)  para armazená-los, assim, você terá somente uma vez cada mac address:

   ```
   def arping(interface, ip):
       p =  subprocess.check_output(['arping', '-I', interface, '-c', '2', ip])
       enderecos = set()
       for line in p.splitlines():
           if line.startswith('Unicast'):
               mac = line.split()[4].strip('[]')
               enderecos.add(mac)
       return enderecos
   ```

Para usar a função:

```
resultado = arping('enp1s0', '192.168.0.1')
print(resultado)
```

Os endereços estão na variável `resultado`, ao usar o `print` vai sair na tela:

```
set(['AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:00', 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01'])
```